# Active Record joins over 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to find all terms and courses that apply to a contact.

Here are my models

```
class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :session
 belongs_to :contact
end

class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :term  
 belongs_to :course
 has_many :registers
 has_many :contacts, :through => :registers
end
```

Here is the find a wrote

```
@data = Register.all :joins => {:session =>[:term, :course]}  , :conditions => ["contact_id = ?", params[:id]]
```

When I run the query all I get is the session records not the terms or courses

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using :include instead of :joins. Something like:

```
@data = Register.all :include => {:session =>[:term, :course]}  , :conditions => ["contact_id = ?", params[:id]]
```